# Как добавить запись в базу данных из связанных таблиц Laravel? Один ко многим и многие ко многим?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

Как добавить запись в базу данных из связанных таблиц Laravel?

Есть таблицы: Авторы, книги и жанры

Связи:

Авторы (один ко многим) книги;

Книги (многие ко многим) жанры.

Как добавить запись в базу данных из связанных таблиц? Один ко многим и многие ко многим?

Есть раздел добавления книги, в котором я хочу задать название книги, указать автора и жанр, но **при добавлении страница просто обновляется**

Так же проблема перекочевала в раздел редактирования. При редактировании страница так же как и в создании **просто обновляется**, но записи в базе данных нет

Страница добавления:

```
    <div class="container">
        <a href="{{ url('books') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Вернуться</a>
        <hr>

        <h2>Добавить новую книгу</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('books.store')}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input name="book" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Название книги">

                @error('book')
                <p class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Авторы:</h3>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <input type="radio" name="name" value="{{$user->id}}">
                    <label>{{$user->name}}</label>
                    <br>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Жанры:</h3>
                @foreach($genres as $genre)
                    <input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="{{$genre->id}}">
                    <label>{{$genre->genre}}</label>
                    <br>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Создать</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Контроллер

```
    public function create()
    {
        return view("admin.books.create", [
            "book" => [],
            "genres" => Genre::get(),
            "users" => User::get()
            ]);
    }

    public function store(BookFormRequest $request)
    {
        $book = Book::create($request->validate());
        $book->users()->create($request->only('name'));

        if($request->input('genres')) :
            $book->genres()->attach($request->input('genres'));
        endif;
        return redirect(route('books', $book));
    }
```

Модель Book

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class, 'book_genre', 'book_id', 'genre_id');
    }
```

Модель Genre

```
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'book_genre', 'genre_id', 'book_id');
    }
```

Модель User

```
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `if: endif;` – так писать вне шаблонов PHP не надо. Почему страница обновляется – включите ошибки и ловите, почему происходит так. `$request->validate()` должен быть `$request->validated()`, чтобы получить отвалидированные данные и не валидировать их снова. Но код Ваш по идее валидный, проверяйте, почему не отправляется. Может быть проблема с самими роутами?

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо! 
Проблема была в `$request->validate()`